# How to Prevent Overlapping Jobs in a Multi-Tenant Laravel Application?

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a multi-tenant Laravel application that receives multiple webhooks from Shopify. Each webhook triggers a job in my application, but I'm encountering an issue where multiple webhooks received at the same timestamp are causing duplicate orders due to concurrent job execution.

I've considered using Laravel's WithoutOverlapping middleware to prevent overlapping jobs, but from my understanding, this works on the command level and won't prevent different jobs from running concurrently.

Here's my specific use case:

I receive multiple webhooks for the same team (e.g., Team A) with the same type (e.g., orders/update) at the same time. I want to ensure that jobs for these webhooks are processed one after another to prevent duplication. However, if a single webhook is received for a different team (e.g., Team B), I want that job to be processed as per the schedule without waiting for Team A's jobs to complete.

Is there a way to prevent job overlapping on a per-team and per-webhook-type basis in Laravel? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the WithoutOverlapping will not work accross tenants, because each tenant will have it's cache. You can try to setup a cache accross tenants with redis for example

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's WithoutOverlapping middleware provides the ability to keep a job unique across multiple different classes through the use of `shared()`:

```php
use Illuminate\Queue\Middleware\WithoutOverlapping;
 
class ProviderIsDown
{
    // ...
 
 
    public function middleware(): array
    {
        return [
            (new WithoutOverlapping("status:{$this->provider}"))->shared(),
        ];
    }
}
```

So in your usecase, having `$teamId` or similar as part of your key would create a shared key that would keep the jobs unique across different classes.

This will work as long as the lock is actually shared between all queue consumers, if there is complete isolation between your queues (e.g `instance1.queue1` is on a different redis instance than `instance2.queue1`) then your locks will be limited to the instance they are running on. In which case the simplest solution would be to setup a central redis for queue handling (which would eliminate the race condition) or to otherwise use the same Redis for caching so that you can use cache locks instead.